# How can I loop this code until row x is reached?

Tags: vba, excel, loops

In column G of my spreadsheet, I would like pull in data from another column. But not each row, only every third row. How can I write a For Until loop that takes every third row and also how do I end the loop?

Here is the code that I need looped every third row in the G column, until row 350.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
Range("G10").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
Range("G13").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
Range("G16").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
```

Also, can anyone recommend an online resource for learning VBA macro-ing in excel?

Comment: you can use "step 3" on loop your cell, if you posto your code, we can help you

Comment: Are there headers in Column F? In which row should the loop start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give you a starting point, try

```
Sub Test()
Dim MyRange As Range, Idx As Integer

    Set MyRange = [G10]          ' define a range object
    Idx = 1                      ' row index

    Do While True                ' see note
        MyRange(Idx, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
        Idx = Idx + 3            ' advance by 3 rows
    Loop
End Sub
```

Here you are working with a Range object rather than selecting and activating cells.

**Important**: Replace `Do While True` by a more suitable termination condition ... like this you're creating an endless loop which is good for testing in the debugger but not for "unattended" execution.

Suitable termination conditions could be

```
Do While MyRange(Idx, 1) <> ""      ' as long as G is not empty
Do While MyRange(Idx, 0) <> ""      ' as long as F is not empty
DO While Idx < 200                  ' until a certain position is reached
```

Comment: this worked perfectly thank you. :) one last question, is there a way I can use this same loop to do something else: 

I have a column with strings and intergers. ex AB 14:25
is there a way I can remove the string characters AND split the 14:25 into to columns?

Comment: sure ... this is a very generic concept of looping thru an exel sheet (and as such should become bread& butter for you) ... define a range / row index / termination condotion ... then inside the loop do whatever has to be done ... e.g. split a time into min's and sec's / delete or insert something ... etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Step 3` like shown below

```
Sub loopThroughColumn()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim LastRow As Integer

    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To LastRow Step 3
        Range("G" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]"
        MsgBox Range("G" & i).Value
    Next

End Sub
```

And you can find online resource for learning VBA [here](http://www.skilledup.com/articles/advanced-excel-vba-programming)